# How do I web scrape Steam after login?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, web-scraping, steam

My goal is to log into Steam's website and populate Excel with my library, and all my friends' libraries to from a table. I can then tabulate & filter what multiplayer games everyone has at the same time, side-by-side.

I've tried the following:

- Internet Explorer, but on the login page, I can't click the login button.
  Even still, if I manually login and then go to a friend's list of games it's empty.
  I think this is an Internet Explorer compatibility issue with Steam's website.
- XML but can't get the setRequestHeader to work with login information.
- Selenium with Microsoft Edge to login but once it executes clicking the login button the browser closes.
- Logging into Steam manually in Microsoft Edge (keeping that window open) then using a macro to get to a friend's game list.
  When the new Microsoft Edge window pops up to the page I'm not logged in so it says their game list is private.

Is there a way of web scraping Steam after logging in?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with `Puppeteer` using `Node.JS`

The trick is to wait until user login in order to continue data extraction. The following is the Script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

// The following function awaits for user input
function askQuestion(query) {
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
                    input: process.stdin,
                    output: process.stdout,
                });

        return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(query, ans => {
                    rl.close();
                    resolve(ans);
                }))
}

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',
        headless: false
    }); //Create browser in non-headless mode.
    const page = await browser.newPage(); //Awaits creation of new page
    await page.goto('https://store.steampowered.com/login/');   //Goes to steam login page
    await askQuestion("Login, then press Enter!");  //Now you login and press enter
    await page.goto('https://steamcommunity.com/id/USERNAME/games/?tab=all');   //Loads the page containing the list of all games of the indicated user

    html = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);   // Gets the HTML web page
    await fs.writeFile("htmlPage", html, err => {});  //Saves it to a file

    console.log(html);
    await browser.close();   // Closes Puppeteer
} 
)();
```

This script creates an instance of `Puppeteer` and opens it in non-headless mode. Then it opens the steam login webpage and waits. At this point, you login manually, go back to console and press Enter. It then opens the page 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/USERNAME/games/?tab=all', and saves the html body to a file called "htmlPage". You can then parse the HTML page however you prefer and get the list of games.

You can extend it if you want it to get the `HTML` body of several pages by doing a for loop (iterating over a list of id's) after you already managed to log in.